# Selenium Webdriver Testing - Python

Tags: python, selenium

I wonder, what is the advantage of using selenium for automation if at the end of the test he emits no reports where the test passed or failed?

Answer (score 6):

Selenium isn't actually a testing framework, it's a browser driver.  You don't write tests in Selenium any more than you write GUI apps in OpenGL.  You usually write tests in a unit testing framework like `unittest`, or something like `nose` or `lettuce` built on top of it.  Your tests then use Selenium to interact with a browser, as they use a database API to access the DB or an HTTP library to communicate with web services.

Comment: Understand. you have a basic example using selenium and unitest?

Answer (score 0):

If using

```
python test_file.py
```

you get at the end an report if there were errors.

Moreover you can take a look at nosetests. 
Passing the "-sv" parameter to nose, it will show you a detailed output which test passed and which not.
Combining nosetests with Xunit you can get valid Xunit-xml reports which can be used in a CI-server like Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

Its up to the discretion of the user what to do with the selenium webdriver automation and how to report the test results. Selenium webdriver will give you the power to control your web browser and to automate your web application tests.

Same as how you have to program in any other automation tool the conditions for checking your pass or fail criteria for any tests, in Selenium also it has to be programmed.It is totally up to the programmer how to report their results and the template to be followed. You will have to write your own code to format and store the test results.